# How to lower frequency of CPU so that it does not change after restart

Tags: cpu

I would like to lower the frequency of CPU.
I tried `cpufrequtils` and more exactly the command

> cpufreq-set -c 0 -u 2.00GHz

It worked, the value of "scaling_max_freq" changed to 2000000. But after I restarted the PC, it was automatically reset to the original value .
I would like to know how to lower the CPU frequency so that it does not change after restarting PC.

Thank you very much!